# Emplace to std::map of std::map

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2012, stl, stdmap

How can I emplace to `std::map<std::string, std::map<std::string,std::string>>`?

tried with `myMap.emplace(std::make_pair("STRING", std::make_pair("STR","STR")))` but got error message `cannot convert std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> to const std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2>`

Comment: `myMap["STRING] = {{"STR", "STR"}};` :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
myMap.emplace(
      std::make_pair(
            "STR1"
         ,   std::map< std::string, std::string>(
                {
                   std::make_pair("STR2", "STR3")
                }
             )
      )
);
```

Should work.

Comment: Did you included <initializer_list> ?

Comment: A little more weird code then: `(std::initializer_list<std::pair<std::string, std::string>>({ std::make_pair("STR2", "STR3") }))` in nested map's constructor, if first variant doesn't really work.

Comment: Initializer lists are not supported by VS2012 :-(

Comment: Ah, yeap, I didn't noticed tag( Then I have another bad idea, but it's not a real emplacing - create nested map outside, and just pass as parameter to first std::make_pair.   And for only interest - here is C++'17 coming, and VS2012 is still actual?)

Comment: In that environment I have to use the old compiler, but nevertheless I will use insert instead of emplace! Thx

Answer (score 0):

Using `std::piecewise_construct` you can `emplace()` as follows

```
   myMap.emplace(
      std::piecewise_construct,
      std::forward_as_tuple("STRING"),
      std::forward_as_tuple(
         std::initializer_list<std::pair<std::string const, std::string>>{
            {"STR", "STR"} }));
```

but I think it's a little clearer emplace an empty map and immediatly after emplace the `"STR"`s in it, as follows

```
   myMap.emplace(std::piecewise_construct,
                 std::forward_as_tuple("STRING"),
                 std::forward_as_tuple()).first->second.emplace("STR", "STR");
```